# Cannot resolve method 'setOnRefreshListener(anonymous android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener)'

Tags: java, android, swipe

I want to implement  Swipe to Refresh to my fragment, it works fine with the xml code, but when it comes to java code , i am getting n error like `Cannot resolve method 'setOnRefreshListener(anonymous android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener)'`

[image]

this is how i implemented in java code

```
import static com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.R.id.swiperefresh;
```

.

```
    swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //view.loadUrl("https://mbasic.facebook.com");


            view.loadUrl("https://mbasic.facebook.com/notifications");

            swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);

        }


    });
```

Comment: What do you have `swiperefresh` declared as, exactly? [Edit] your question to show the declaration and initialization code.

Comment: only this much i have added in java code , i will edit answer

Comment: you are using v4.widget.swipeReferesh layout but your import is different. either change import or use that import swipeLayout

Comment: That `swiperefresh` is not a `SwipeRefreshLayout` reference. It's an ID that you'd use to get the `SwipeRefreshLayout` object created from your layout, with `findViewById()`. You should really start with some tutorials for Android basics.

Comment: thanks bro, i got it@MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is should be like this:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mswipeRefreshLayout;

mswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

              //write your code here.
              //
                mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```